# Ionic Cordova - Contact Plugin Project

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying Contact plugin in my project which will load and create contacts in your phone. I had built and ran the project through the command prompt. Both were successful and I can see the buttons on my phone as well. The problem is that when I click on them, nothing happens. I have pasted the code I had used below :

In **home.page.html** :

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Contact Plugin Demo
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <ion-header collapse="condense">
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title size="large">Contact Management Demo</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <div id="container">
    <ion-button (click) = "loadContacts()" expand="full">Load Contacts</ion-button>
    <ion-button (click)="createContacts()" expand = "full">Create Contacts</ion-button>

    <ion-list>
      <ion-item-sliding *ngFor = "let c of myContacts">
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>
            {{c.name.givenName}}
            <b>{{c.name.familyName}}</b>
            <p>{{c.phoneNumbers[0].value}}</p>
          </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item-options side="end">
          <ion-item-option (click)="call(c)" color="primary">
            <ion-icon name="call" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
          </ion-item-option>
          <ion-item-option (click)="sendSMS(c)" color="secondary">
            <ion-icon name="mail" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
          </ion-item-option>
        </ion-item-options>
      </ion-item-sliding>
    </ion-list>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

In **home.page.ts** :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Contact, ContactField, ContactName } from '@ionic-native/contacts/ngx';
import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number/ngx';
import { SMS } from '@ionic-native/sms/ngx';
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';

/*
ngx - 
ToastController - 
*/

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  myContacts: Contact[] = [];
  constructor(private contact:Contact,
    private callNumber:CallNumber,
    private sms:SMS,
    private ToastCntrl:ToastController) {}

    loadContacts(){
      let options = {
        filter: '',
        multiple: true,
        hasPhoneNumber: true
      };

      this.contact.find(['*'],options).then((contact:Contact[]) =>{
        this.myContacts = contact;
        console.log('Contacts: ', contact);
      });
    }

    sendSMS(contact:Contact){this.sms.send(contact.phoneNumbers[0].value,
                              'This is my predefined message for you');
          }
    call(contact:Contact){
      this.callNumber.callNumber(contact.phoneNumbers[0].value,true);
    }

    createContact(){
      let contact: Contact=this.contact.create();

      contact.name = new ContactName(null,'Anjana','Kizhiyapat');
      contact.phoneNumbers = [new ContactField('mobile','1234567890')];
      contact.save().then(
        async () => {
          let toast = await this.ToastCntrl.create({
            message: 'Contact added'
          });
          toast.present();
        },
        (error:any) => console.error('Error saving contact!' , error)
      );
    }
}
```

In **app.module.ts** :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { Contact } from '@ionic-native/contacts/ngx';
import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number/ngx';
import { SMS } from '@ionic-native/sms/ngx';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    CallNumber,
    Contact, SMS],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Can you build with alerts of important values, inserted at breakpoints? Just to see if/what errors you're getting when using on the device?

Comment: May I know how to do that? Sorry, I am new to this

Comment: Put `alert(JSON.stringify(contacts))` before `this.myContacts = contact;` to see what you're really having returned. Also, it would be good to handle errors and put alert there too.

Comment: I had tried it, still the same issue...nothing happens when the button is pressed

Comment: Try the code from https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/contacts/ and do alert instead of console.log for success and error. Just to see if the issue is in your code or android permissions.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It is working well...I got some assistance from a github repository as well (https://github.com/AndrewJBateman/ionic-angular-contacts)